# android zxing scanner doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, zxing

in my android app i have include the Zxing barcode scanner.
This works fine, but one little and important thing doesnt work
My App can only be use in portait mode.

if i scan a barcode, which is horizontal (same like the red line), the barcode will be detected:

[Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68TJG.png)

But if I scan a barcode, which is not vertical instead horizontal, the barcode will be not detected:
[Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVt0m.png)

This is the complete class of my barcode scanner.
Have you any ideas how i can solve this problem?

```
package me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.sample;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class Scanner extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
   private static final String CAMERA_ID = "CAMERA_ID";
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
   private int mCameraId = -1;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setContentView(R.layout.barcode_scanner);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        if(state != null) {
           mCameraId = state.getInt(CAMERA_ID, -1);
        } else {
           mCameraId = -1;
        }


        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ScannerLayout);
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        relativeLayout.addView(mScannerView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera(mCameraId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(CAMERA_ID, mCameraId);
    }


    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Scanner.this, LoadingData.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }
}
```